# User implemented SHA-1 isn't outputting correct hash

Tags: code-review, cryptography, hashing

**EDIT**: I'm actually Thinking the issue is in the initialization phase, where we pad the message with `1`'s, `0`'s, and the message length.

**EDIT EDIT** See the bottom of the post, I've run out of ideas.. ):

I'm creating a user implemented [SHA-1 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), and I can't seem to figure out why it's outputting the incorrect hash for whitespace, which I'm using as a test case (00100000).Any suggestions on where I've gone wrong would be much appreciated.

```
 ef[t_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Which[0 <= t <= 19, (BitOr[BitAnd[b, c], BitAnd[BitNot[b], d]]), 
   20 <= t <= 39, BitXor[b, c, d], 
   40 <= t <= 59, (BitOr[BitAnd[b, c], BitAnd[b, d], BitAnd[c, d]]), 
   60 <= t <= 79, BitXor[b, c, d]];

k[t_] := Which[0 <= t <= 19, FromDigits["5a827999", 16], 
   20 <= t <= 39, FromDigits["6ed9eba1", 16], 40 <= t <= 59, 
   FromDigits["8f1bbcdc", 16], 60 <= t <= 79, 
   FromDigits["ca62c1d6", 16]];

h[t_] := Which[t == 1, FromDigits["67452301", 16], t == 2, 
   FromDigits["efcdab89", 16], t == 3, FromDigits["98badcfe", 16], 
   t == 4, FromDigits["10325476", 16], t == 5, 
   FromDigits["c3d2e1f0", 16]];

CirclePlus[x__] := Mod[Plus[x], 2^32];

sha1[msg_] := 
 Module[{pp, eta, g, ff, temp, al, v, fs, i, test, jj, list, output, 
   r, l, L, w, x, a, b, c, d, e, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5},
  r = msg;
  l = Length[r];
  L = Floor[l/512] + 1;
  AppendTo[r, Join[{1}, Table[0, {512 - (l + 65)}]]];
  AppendTo[r, IntegerDigits[l, 2, 64]];
  r = Flatten[r];
  w = Table[r[[512 i + 1 ;; 512 (i + 1)]], {i, 0, L - 1}];
  {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5} = {h[1], h[2], h[3], h[4], h[5]};
  x = Table[
    FromDigits[w[[i]][[32*j + 1 ;; 32*(j + 1)]], 2], {i, 1, L}, {j, 0,
      15}];
  Echo[x];
  For[i = 1, i <= L, i++,
   For[fs = 17, fs <= 80, fs++,
    temp = 
     RotateLeft[
      IntegerDigits[
       BitXor[x[[i, fs - 3]], x[[i, fs - 8]], x[[i, fs - 14]], 
        x[[i, fs - 16]]], 2, 32], 1];
    temp = FromDigits[temp, 2];
    AppendTo[x[[i]], temp];
    ];
   Echo[x];
   {a, b, c, d, e} = {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5};
   For[jj = 1, jj <= 80, jj++,
    Echo[a];
    a = RotateLeft[IntegerDigits[a, 2, 32], 5];
    a = FromDigits[a, 2];
    Echo[a];
    pp = ef[jj - 1, b, c, d];
    test = CirclePlus[a, pp, e, x[[i, jj]], k[jj - 1]];
    e = d;
    d = c;
    c = RotateLeft[IntegerDigits[b, 2, 32], 30];
    c = FromDigits[c, 2];
    b = a;
    a = test;
    ];

   {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5} = {h1\[CirclePlus]a, h2\[CirclePlus]b, 
     h3\[CirclePlus]c, h4\[CirclePlus]d, h5\[CirclePlus]e};
   ];
  list = {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5};
  output = 
   BitOr[2^128*list[[1]], 2^96*list[[2]], 2^64*list[[3]], 
    2^32*list[[4]], list[[5]]];
  {output, BaseForm[output, 16]}
  ]
```

> sha1[{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}]
>
> fcc7c975ba0df390bc9e7e8541498738e71be6cf

However, the actual value is

> b858cb282617fb0956d960215c8e84d1ccf909c6

Any suggestions? After about 10 hours of playing with random things to see if they were the issue, I'm kind of out of ideas. Could the error be contained within `ef`? I tried replacing `ef` with the following:

```
ef[t_, b1_, c1_, d1_] := 
  Module[{apb, b, c, d}, {b, c, d} = 
    IntegerDigits[{b1, c1, d1}, 2, 32]; 
   apb = Which[
     0 <= t <= 19, (BitOr[BitAnd[b, c], BitAnd[BitNot[b], d]]), 
     20 <= t <= 39, BitXor[b, c, d], 
     40 <= t <= 59, (BitOr[BitAnd[b, c], BitAnd[b, d], BitAnd[c, d]]),
      60 <= t <= 79, BitXor[b, c, d]];
   FromDigits[apb, 2]];
```

Which changed nothing. ):

Comment: It would be nice if it was generalized to include SHA-2, SHA-3 and the Shaker functions.

Comment: I'm new to writing cryptographic hash functions, give me some slack and some time, I'll get there :)

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: As I discovered later, this code only functions for strings that are represented as a number of bits between `512K > s > 512K-64`, for number of bits needed to represent the string `s` ( it may be 512K-65, I was trying adding one byte at a time during testing. For example, it works upto 440 bits, stopped at 448, began working again at 512, and this pattern repeated for each multiple of 512), for K an integer [1,2,3...]. At the end of this post I will include a link to the correct implementation for all string lengths.

Here is a correctly inmplemented code (except for note above), I was rewriting `a` with `RotateLeft[a,5]` which threw everything out of whack.

```
ef[t_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Which[0 <= t <= 19, (BitOr[BitAnd[b, c], BitAnd[BitNot[b], d]]), 
   20 <= t <= 39, BitXor[b, c, d], 
   40 <= t <= 59, (BitOr[BitAnd[b, c], BitAnd[b, d], BitAnd[c, d]]), 
   60 <= t <= 79, BitXor[b, c, d]];

k[t_] := Which[0 <= t <= 19, FromDigits["5a827999", 16], 
   20 <= t <= 39, FromDigits["6ed9eba1", 16], 40 <= t <= 59, 
   FromDigits["8f1bbcdc", 16], 60 <= t <= 79, 
   FromDigits["ca62c1d6", 16]];

h[t_] := Which[t == 1, FromDigits["67452301", 16], t == 2, 
   FromDigits["efcdab89", 16], t == 3, FromDigits["98badcfe", 16], 
   t == 4, FromDigits["10325476", 16], t == 5, 
   FromDigits["c3d2e1f0", 16]];
CirclePlus[x__] := Mod[Plus[x], 2^32];

sha1[msg_] := 
 Module[{pp, eta, g, ff, temp, al, v, fs, i, test, jj, list, output, 
   r, l, L, w, x, a, b, c, d, e, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5},
  r = msg;
  l = Length[r];
  L = Floor[l/512] + 1;
  AppendTo[r, Join[{1}, Table[0, {512 - (l + 65)}]]];
  AppendTo[r, IntegerDigits[l, 2, 64]];
  r = Flatten[r];
  w = Table[r[[512 i + 1 ;; 512 (i + 1)]], {i, 0, L - 1}];
  {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5} = {h[1], h[2], h[3], h[4], h[5]};
  For[i = 1, i <= L, i++,
   Clear[x];
   x = Table[
     FromDigits[w[[i]][[32*j + 1 ;; 32*(j + 1)]], 2], {j, 0, 15}];
   For[fs = 17, fs <= 80, fs++,
    temp = 
     RotateLeft[
      IntegerDigits[
       BitXor[x[[fs - 3]], x[[fs - 8]], x[[fs - 14]], x[[fs - 16]]], 
       2, 32], 1];
    temp = FromDigits[temp, 2];
    AppendTo[x, temp];
    ];
   {a, b, c, d, e} = {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5};
   For[jj = 1, jj <= 80, jj++,
    al = RotateLeft[IntegerDigits[a, 2, 32], 5];
    al = FromDigits[al, 2];
    pp = ef[jj - 1, b, c, d];
    test = 
     al\[CirclePlus]pp\[CirclePlus]e\[CirclePlus]x[[jj]]\[CirclePlus]\
k[jj - 1];
    e = d;
    d = c;
    c = RotateLeft[IntegerDigits[b, 2, 32], 30];
    c = FromDigits[c, 2];
    b = a;
    a = test;
    ];

   {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5} = {h1\[CirclePlus]a, h2\[CirclePlus]b, 
     h3\[CirclePlus]c, h4\[CirclePlus]d, h5\[CirclePlus]e};
   ];
  list = {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5};
  output = 
   BitOr[2^128*list[[1]], 2^96*list[[2]], 2^64*list[[3]], 
    2^32*list[[4]], list[[5]]];
  output2 = IntegerDigits[Flatten[list], 2, 32];
  output2 = FromDigits[Flatten[output2], 2];
  outputa = BaseForm[output2, 16];
  {output, output2, outputa, BaseForm[output, 16]}
  ]
```

One that works for a string of any length is included in my answer to my own question( again), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195574/user-implemented-sha-1-is-failing-for-strings-of-length-512-bits/195581?noredirect=1#comment508950_195581).