# User Implemented SHA-1 is failing for strings of length >512 bits

Tags: function-construction, code-review, broken-code, cryptography

So, earlier, I posed a question [regarding getting a user implemented SHA-1 hash function to work correctly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194746/user-implemented-sha-1-isnt-outputting-correct-hash). Well, I fixed the problems, cleaned it up a little bit, but now I have the problem for when the string's length is greater then 512 bits, the hash function is not operating correctly. Below is the code:
The issue appears to be when the `512>Length[message]>448`. Any suggestions?

```
 ef[t_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Which[0 <= t <= 19, (BitOr[BitAnd[b, c], BitAnd[BitNot[b], d]]), 
   20 <= t <= 39, BitXor[b, c, d], 
   40 <= t <= 59, (BitOr[BitAnd[b, c], BitAnd[b, d], BitAnd[c, d]]), 
   60 <= t <= 79, BitXor[b, c, d]];

k[t_] := Which[0 <= t <= 19, FromDigits["5a827999", 16], 
   20 <= t <= 39, FromDigits["6ed9eba1", 16], 40 <= t <= 59, 
   FromDigits["8f1bbcdc", 16], 60 <= t <= 79, 
   FromDigits["ca62c1d6", 16]];

CirclePlus[x__] := Mod[Plus[x], 2^32];

sha1[msg_] := 
 Module[{pp, eta, temp, al, v, test, fs, jj, i, output, r, l, L, w, x, a, b,
  c, d, e, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, \[Beta]},
  \[Beta] = Characters[msg];
  r = Flatten[IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode[#], 2, 8] & /@ \[Beta]];
  l = Length[r];
  L = Floor[l/512] + 1;
  l = Mod[l, 512];
  Echo[L];
  AppendTo[r, Join[{1}, Table[0, {512 - (l + 65)}]]];
  AppendTo[r, IntegerDigits[l, 2, 64]];
  r = Flatten[r];
  Echo[Length[r]];
  w = Table[r[[512 i + 1 ;; 512 (i + 1)]], {i, 0, L - 1}];
  Table[Echo[Length[w[[u]]]], {u, 1, L}];
  {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5} = {FromDigits["67452301", 16], 
    FromDigits["efcdab89", 16], FromDigits["98badcfe", 16], 
    FromDigits["10325476", 16], FromDigits["c3d2e1f0", 16]};
  For[i = 1, i <= L, i++,

   x = Table[
     FromDigits[w[[i]][[32*j + 1 ;; 32*(j + 1)]], 2], {j, 0, 15}];

   For[fs = 17, fs <= 80, fs++,
    temp = 
     FromDigits[
      RotateLeft[
       IntegerDigits[
        BitXor[x[[fs - 3]], x[[fs - 8]], x[[fs - 14]], x[[fs - 16]]], 
        2, 32], 1], 2];
    AppendTo[x, temp];
    ];

   {a, b, c, d, e} = {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5};

   For[jj = 1, jj <= 80, jj++,
    al = FromDigits[RotateLeft[IntegerDigits[a, 2, 32], 5], 2];
    pp = ef[jj - 1, b, c, d];
    test = 
     al\[CirclePlus]pp\[CirclePlus]e\[CirclePlus]x[[
       jj]]\[CirclePlus]k[jj - 1];
    e = d;
    d = c;
    c = FromDigits[RotateLeft[IntegerDigits[b, 2, 32], 30], 2];
    b = a;
    a = test;
    ];

   {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5} = {h1\[CirclePlus]a, h2\[CirclePlus]b, 
     h3\[CirclePlus]c, h4\[CirclePlus]d, h5\[CirclePlus]e};
   ];
  output = BitOr[2^128*h1, 2^96*h2, 2^64*h3, 2^32*h4, h5];
  {output, BaseForm[output, 16]}
  ]
```

Some case tests:

```
 f = "Signed by Administrator on April 19th 2019";
 r = sha1[f][[1]];
 t = Hash[f, "SHA"];
 r - t
```

> 0

And, with more than 512 bits,

```
f = "Signed by Administrator on April 19th 2019, testing a string greater than 512 bits"

r = sha1[f][[1]];
t = Hash[f, "SHA"];
r - t
```

> 9b4cc069c8b83cb8635781d61791a4d0b6397631

Lets try another random sentence:

```
f = "I really wish I could understand the problem."
r = sha1[f][[1]]
t = Hash[f, "SHA"]
r - t
```

> 0

```
f = "I really wish I could understand the problem. This is extremely
irritating, I feel as though I've implemented this correctly!!!"
r = sha1[f][[1]]
t = Hash[f, "SHA"]
r - t
```

> 41450d1c29b13d9446ab95ef81b516f9c5fe2c85

I'd LOVE any ideas on where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The following changes to the beginning of the code (all before the first `For[]` loop) fixes the code for any amount of bits/ bytes.

```
ef[t_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Which[0 <= t <= 19, (BitOr[BitAnd[b, c], BitAnd[BitNot[b], d]]), 
   20 <= t <= 39, BitXor[b, c, d], 
   40 <= t <= 59, (BitOr[BitAnd[b, c], BitAnd[b, d], BitAnd[c, d]]), 
   60 <= t <= 79, BitXor[b, c, d]];

k[t_] := Which[0 <= t <= 19, FromDigits["5a827999", 16], 
   20 <= t <= 39, FromDigits["6ed9eba1", 16], 40 <= t <= 59, 
   FromDigits["8f1bbcdc", 16], 60 <= t <= 79, 
   FromDigits["ca62c1d6", 16]];

CirclePlus[x__] := Mod[Plus[x], 2^32];

sha1[msg_] := 
 Module[{pp, eta, temp, al, v, fs, jj, ll, i, output, r, l, L, w, x, 
   a, b, c, d, e, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, \[Eta], \[Beta]}, \[Beta] = 
   Characters[msg]; 
  r = Flatten[IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode[#], 2, 8] & /@ \[Beta]]; 
  l = Length[r]; Echo[l];
  lj = Mod[l + 65, 512]; L = Floor[(l + 65)/512] + 1; 
  AppendTo[r, Join[{1}, Table[0, {512 - (lj)}]]]; 
  AppendTo[r, IntegerDigits[l, 2, 64]]; r = Flatten[r]; 
  Echo[Length[r]];
  Echo[L]; w = Table[r[[512 i + 1 ;; 512 (i + 1)]], {i, 0, L - 1}]; 
  Table[Echo[Length[w[[u]]]], {u, 1, L}]; {h1, h2, h3, h4, 
    h5} = {FromDigits["67452301", 16], FromDigits["efcdab89", 16], 
    FromDigits["98badcfe", 16], FromDigits["10325476", 16], 
    FromDigits["c3d2e1f0", 16]}; 
  For[i = 1, i <= L, i++, 
   x = Table[
     FromDigits[w[[i]][[32*j + 1 ;; 32*(j + 1)]], 2], {j, 0, 15}]; 
   For[fs = 17, fs <= 80, fs++, 
    temp = FromDigits[
      RotateLeft[
       IntegerDigits[
        BitXor[x[[fs - 3]], x[[fs - 8]], x[[fs - 14]], x[[fs - 16]]], 
        2, 32], 1], 2];
    AppendTo[x, temp];]; {a, b, c, d, e} = {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5}; 
   For[jj = 1, jj <= 80, jj++, 
    al = FromDigits[RotateLeft[IntegerDigits[a, 2, 32], 5], 2];
    pp = ef[jj - 1, b, c, d];
    temp = 
     al\[CirclePlus]pp\[CirclePlus]e\[CirclePlus]x[[jj]]\[CirclePlus]\
k[jj - 1];
    e = d;
    d = c;
    c = FromDigits[RotateLeft[IntegerDigits[b, 2, 32], 30], 2];
    b = a;
    a = temp;];
   {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5} = {h1\[CirclePlus]a, h2\[CirclePlus]b, 
     h3\[CirclePlus]c, h4\[CirclePlus]d, h5\[CirclePlus]e};]; 
  output = BitOr[2^128*h1, 2^96*h2, 2^64*h3, 2^32*h4, h5]; {output, 
   BaseForm[output, 16]}]
```

Speicifcally, we change this section

```
  L = Floor[l/512] + 1;
  l = Mod[l, 512];
  Echo[L];
  AppendTo[r, Join[{1}, Table[0, {512 - (l + 65)}]]];
  AppendTo[r, IntegerDigits[l, 2, 64]];
  r = Flatten[r];
```

To

```
 lj = Mod[l + 65, 512]; 
 L = Floor[(l + 65)/512] + 1; 
 AppendTo[r, Join[{1}, Table[0, {512 - (lj)}]]]; 
 AppendTo[r, IntegerDigits[l, 2, 64]];
 r = Flatten[r];
```

Comment: Nice to see that you could fix the problem yourself. However, your answer implies that the code in your [other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194781/18476) in incorrect. You might also correct it there or add a link to this answer to it.

Comment: I had thought it was correct when I posted that question's answer, and didn't consider to go back and edit it. I've added it to the answer in the other post.